# PHP GD Reflection with original picture on top

Tags: php, image, gd

I have stumbled upon a nice PHP library that uses GD to generate a reflection of a picture.

I tried to modify the way so it also display the original image above its reflection to not have to align them in HTML.

The script can be found there :
http://reflection.corephp.co.uk/v3.php

Any idea if this can be done easily ? With my tests, the alpha gradient effect wasnt applied at all.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By reading the comments on the page. Someone posted a way to do it.

The codes can be found there:

http://www.corephp.co.uk/archives/48-Easy-Reflections-v2.1-Released.html